# BCrypt.checkpw not working (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, hash, passwords, bcrypt

My web app uses BCrypt to encrypt user password and save it to MySQL (column data type: **varchar(255)**)

```
BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt(15));
```

However, when the user logins, the BCrypt.checkpw fails to match the password that is the same as the one used in registration (before hashing).

```
boolean passwordMatch = BCrypt.checkpw(password, user.getPassword()); //false
```

I don't know what's happening. Does anyone have an idea where I should check?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that it doesn't seem having anything to do with BCrypt, because I tried to recompile my web app, and the login works, however, I don't understand why it requires a recompile though.

Answer (score 0):

```
BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt(15));//this is when you insert
//********
boolean passwordMatch = BCrypt.checkpw( plainPassword , myPasswordOnDB);
```

(`plainPassword` is the String password and `myPasswordOnDB` is the encrypted password)

This is the right way of checking a password. If that doesn't work for you try making the mySQL column password char(60).